# Converting floats from input into integers within an equation python

Tags: python, integer, logic

Program is supposed to take an integer and a factor of x and evaluate the polynomial `a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+ ... a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0`, where each `a_i` is a coefficient of the corresponding power of x.

Basically, the polynomial `3x^4+2x^3+x+5` can be represented as the integer 32015 since the `x^2` coefficient is 0. It is then evaluated by the x value. However, the program won't accept decimals for the first integer as input but wants all decimals to be included in the answer.

I've written most of the program.

```
while True:
  try:
    number = list(reversed(input()))
    if int("".join(number)):
      break
  except:
    print("Invalid Input")

while True:
  try:
    x = float(input())
    break
  except:
    print("Invalid Input")



degree = len(number)

result = 0

for i in range(degree):
  result += int(number[i]) * pow(x,i)

print(result)
```

However, for the inputs 341 and -2.9, the program expects

```
218.11999999999998
```

but is recieving

```
218.11999999999995
```

How can I stop the decimals in the answer from being rounded?

Comment: Seems like a floating point arithmetic error. I'd do some more research into floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I've researched about floating-point numbers and the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) also state this as an error. However, what they recommend is using [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) which is a built-in function to convert your input into 17 significant digits. You could also create an `if` condition that runs the `repr()` function only when required.

**Why does this problem occur?** Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions. For example, the decimal fraction 0.125 has value 1/10 + 2/100 + 5/1000, and in the same way the binary fraction 0.001 has value 0/2 + 0/4 + 1/8. These two fractions have identical values, the only real difference being that the first is written in base 10 fractional notation, and the second in base 2.